# C++: Doubling digits using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

This is for my "Intro to C++" course. I need to

> Write a program that uses a recursive function double_all_digit that doubles all digit from an integer. For example, `double_all_digits(101)` will return `110011`

My code below works for only one digit; I have no idea how to proceed:

```
int double_all_digit(int x)
{
    if(x < 10)
        return (x*10) + x;
}
```

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the base case; now for the recursion.

- split the number into the 1's digit (use modulus) and the rest.
- recur on the rest; your result is that number with all the digits doubled.
- multiply that result by 100; add 11 times the 1's digit.
- return this value up one level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy:

- convert a digit to a string.  (use std::to_string)
- iterate over characters in the string and append 2 characters in a new string for each character in the original.  (See std::string::append)
- convert the resulting string to an integer.

Since it's homework, you'll have to do the coding bit. :)

Comment: how can this be realized by a *recursive function*